# Random parameters amount in {% url %} tag in Django templatess

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I just want to apologize for my bad English. 
(I'm from Russia)

So, I want to add pagination on my site. 
Imagine, we have two pages: ***site.com/*** (as main page), on which there is posts list, 
and ***site.com/tag/tagname*** - posts list by tag.

Both pages must have a paginator. 
I want to create individual template for pagination block ***paginator.html*** and include this in ***index.html*** and ***tag.html***.

Page urls must be looks like: ***site.com/5*** and ***site.com/tag/tagname/5***. So, we have a different amount of parameters for ***{% url %}*** tag: 1 for main page and 2 for tag page.

Just simple example:

***urls.py:***

```
app_name = 'test_app'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<page_num>[0-9]+)$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_name>[-\w]+)$', views.tag, name = 'tag'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<page_num>[0-9]+)$', views.tag, name = 'tag'),
]
```

***views.py***

```
def paginate(objects_list, in_page, page_num):
    paginator = Paginator(objects_list, in_page)
    page = paginator.page(page_num)
    return page

def index(request, page_num = 1):
    page = paginate(questions, 5, page_num)
    return render(request, 'test_app/index.html', {
        'questions': page,
    })

def tag(request, tag_name, page_num = 1):
    page = paginate(questions, 5, page_num)
    return render(request, 'test_app/tag.html', {
        'questions': page,
        'tag_name': tag_name,
    })
```

questions is a list of questions.

***index.html***

```
{% for question in questions %}
    Author: {{ question.author }} <br>
    Title: {{ question.title }} <br>
    Body: {{ question.body }} <br>
{% endfor %}

{% load i18n %}
{% trans "test_app:index" as page_url %}
{% include "./paginator.html" %}
```

***tag.html***

```
Posts by tag: {{ tag_name }} <br> <br>
{% for question in questions %}
    Author: {{ question.author }} <br>
    Title: {{ question.title }} <br>
    Body: {{ question.body }} <br>
{% endfor %}

{% load i18n %}
{% trans "test_app:tag" as page_url %}
{% trans tag_name as var1 %}
{% include "./paginator.html" %}
```

And ***paginator.html***

```
{% if questions.has_previous %}
    <a href = "{% url page_url 1 %}"><button> &lt;&lt; </button></a>
    <a href = "{% url page_url var1 questions.previous_page_number %}"><button> {{ questions.previous_page_number }} </button></a>
{% endif %}

<a><button> {{ questions.number }} </button></a>

{% if questions.has_next %}
    <a href = "{% url page_url var1 questions.next_page_number %}"><button> {{ questions.next_page_number }} </button></a>
    <a href = "{% url page_url var1 questions.paginator.num_pages %}"><button> &gt;&gt; </button></a>
{% endif %}
```

I tried to run this example. It's works good for tag.html.

For index.html i have this message:

> NoReverseMatch at /test/
>   Reverse for 'index' with arguments '('', 2)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['test/(?P[0-9]+)$', 'test/$']

And so my quesion. 
HOW I can to use {% url %} tag, inside of tamplate like a paginator.html, if I don't know, how many parameters my current URL contain?

Also, I just want to use variable name instead of "questions" in paginator.html.

I tried this:

in tag.html and index.html I write:
    {% trans question as page_object %}

And use "page_object" instead of "questions" in paginator.html. But I have error message:

> 'Page' object has no attribute 'replace'
>
> {% trans question as page_object %}

I tried several variants, and all they don't work good. I dont't know, what can I do yet.

I don't want to paste paginator in each page.